# Changing the associated google-account for Ingress

Tags: ingress

I made the mistake of using a Google-for-Business-Account for Ingress when I started almost 3 years ago.

I'm no more related to this company so they deactivated my account and thus I lost access to Ingress.

Is there any possibility to transfer an Ingress-account to another Google-Account? I read on Niantic's sites that this is not possible. But this was before they "split up" with Google.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible. What you can change, that is your linked G+ profile in the game, not your google profile.

What you can do is to ask your old company to create that email address for you again.

If you have more google profile on your mobile, you can logout, and sign in with a different account, but that will be another agent.

So you need to start from scratch.

Or you can start a ticket at NIA, and explain the whole story, and ask them to change your email, but do not hope....